# Graphs and equivalence relation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, coloring

> There is a graph $G$ whose set of vertices is $V(G) = \{ 1 \dots nm \}$ and the edges are $ E(G) = \{ a,b \}$ so that two vertices are connected iff $a - b \equiv 0 \mod m$, where $a,b \in \{ 1 \dots nm \}$ for $n, m \in \mathbb{N}$. Find the chromatic polynomial of this graph and its chromatic number.

I have been able to obtain it, but I want to be sure that my question is right. Here is my attempt:

Since $a-b \equiv 0\mod m$, there are up to $m$ equivalence classes (in this case, remainders when dividing by $m$). Therefore, there are $m$ connected compontents of this graph, independent between them. Besides, since $a,b \in \{ 1 \dots nm \}$, each of this equivalence classes contains $n$ elements, (this is, every compontent of the graph has $n$ vertex), and since this equivalence relation is obviously transitive, each of those vertices are connected with each other, this is, there are $m$ independent $K_n$'s, where $K_n$ is the complete graph of $n$ vertices. Therefore, the chromatic polynomial of $G$ is $P_G(x) = (P_{K_n}(x))^m$, where the last expression is the chromatic polynomial of the complete graph of $n$ vertex. The chromatic number is therefore $ \chi(G) = n$. Am I right?